# EF one to many relationship using different columns instead of ID(primary key)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
[Table("FirstClass")]
public class FirstClass {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SpecialID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SecondClass> SecondClassList { get; set; }
}

[Table("SecondClass")]    
public class SecondClass {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentSpecialID { get; set;}

    public virtual FirstClass FirstClass { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map these classes with 'SpecialID' and 'ParentSpecialID'.
Is there an any way to do it?

Comment: You're trying to model a hierarchy, not a one-to-many relation. You *won't* be able to get children or parents if you try to treat this as a 1:M relation, not even in SQL. You'd need a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-a-recursive-common-table-expression-to-display-multiple-levels-of-recursion) for this. The best way to do that is to use a [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) column

Comment: thanks for comment. i am going to watch it.

Comment: A `hierarchyid` makes querying a lot easier and far faster, but it's still not supported in EF or EF Core (CTEs can't be expressed in LINQ either). You'd have to use raw SQL for the initial query. In EF Core you can use [FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for the initial query that includes the hierarchical constraing, and add LINQ on top of it for extra filters, selections, etc

Comment: Think of it as of a Folder Tree. It's folder containing Folders, not two different classes.
In small databases (up to 10000 items) you can consider to load the entire tables, that's really easier to handle, than loading one by one, cause each hierarchy level does need a separate query otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to map these classes with 'SpecialID' and 'ParentSpecialID'. Is there an any way to do it?

Yes, but only in EF Core which supports [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys).

Well you can *sort of* do this in EF 6 too, if you declare `SpecialID` to be the Entity Key of `FirstClass`.  Both `ID` and `SpecialID` must have unique indexes in the database, and so either one can be used as the Entity Key.  But then all relationships refering to FirstClass must use `SpecialID`.